# Get property of polygons that a point is in GEE

Tags: python-3.x, google-earth-engine

I'm new to Google Earth Engine, am using a Python API, and am stuck on a problem.  I have a `featureCollection` of points and another `featureCollection` of polygons ([FAO data on country borders](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/FAO_GAUL_2015_level0#table-schema)). I want to find the country each point lies in and add its name as a property to the points. I found this [code example](https://code.earthengine.google.com/81293037572ccd73f4da36460c3b9e3b) for GEE which seems to do what I'm looking for, but I can't figure out what the translation would be in the Python API, which I have to use to export my data in chunks. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Also worth noting there are a lot of points in my data, so the most efficient option is very appreciated. Thank you!